# Why does SQL generate an inefficient plan with a simple OR condition added to this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider a MySQL DB with 2 tables: **member**, **following**, where **following** is a join table of following relationship from **member** to itself.

- members is 100k rows
- following is 1.3m rows

This query is very fast, runs in < 1s

```
select distinct m.id
from member m
 join following t1 on m.id = t1.to_member_id
 join following t2 on t1.from_member_id = t2.to_member_id
where (t2.from_member_id = 1)
```

However, when I add an OR condition

```
select distinct m.id
from member m
 join following t1 on m.id = t1.to_member_id
 join following t2 on t1.from_member_id = t2.to_member_id
where (t2.from_member_id = 1 OR m.id = 2)
```

the query runs in 15s!

The query plans are like the following respectively,

[image]

[image]

So why does that simple OR condition change the plan so drastically?

I would have imaged the server would internally just union the two sets? Anyway, I did try the below and indeed the query is much faster again.

```
select distinct m.id
from member m
 join following t1 on m.id = t1.to_member_id
 join following t2 on t1.from_member_id = t2.to_member_id
where t2.from_member_id = 1 
union distinct
select m.id from m.id = 2
```

But is there anyway I can structure the query, but still with the OR condition, or somehow give it hints so that it generates a better plan?  I'm asking this because the actual query is generated by a framework and it's not always possible to wrap multiple sub-conditions inside a union statement.

Comment: is this a typo?  `m.id == 2`  I'm no mysql guru, but I've never seen a double equality in mysql.

Comment: Btw, `select m.id from member as m where m.id = 2` is exactly the same as `select 2`.

Comment: `OR` makes it hard for MySQL to use indexes. A single query can usually only use one index, so it has to choose between the index on `m.id` or `t2.from_member_id`. Whichever one it chooses, it will then have to use a full scan for the other one.

Comment: @dnoeth not *exactly* the same. `select 2` always returns a row, but the select from table requires there to be a row with that id. Exactly same would be `select 2 from member where id = 2`

Comment: To "fix", split the query into 2 queries - one for each of the `or` conditions - and `union` them

Comment: @Bohemian:  Of course, you're correct, the select will not return a row when there's no row with `2`. But that's the same for `select 2 from member where id = 2` :-)

Comment: @dnoeth that's what I'm trying to tell you. To fix `select 2` to make it the same as OP's query you would have to add the where clause.

Comment: You should remove `distinct` from your suggested query. It isn't needed because `union` removes duplicates. Plus the second `distinct` is a syntax error - it's in the wrong place; `distinct` cones after `select` not after `union`

Comment: @Bohemian: `UNION DISTINCT` is valid syntax, of course nobody uses ist, because it's the default :). Similar: you can write `SELECT ALL` in Standard SQL, but it's the default anyway.

Comment: @devlincarnate right, that == is a typo

Answer (score 0):

If you dont use the OR condition mysql can use indexes very efficiently, when you use OR however, it actually has to go one by one evaluating them, and the process its a lot slower, i would suggest using two queries and UNION them.